# Is there a simpler solution for this?

Tags: python

I am currently a beginner is pythonand I want to know what's a simpler way doing this method below?

```
for i in range (20100,20130):
    print ("s0", i, "@gmail.com", sep='')


for i in range (20200,20230):
    print ("s0", i, "@gmail.com", sep='')

for i in range (20300,20330):
    print ("s0", i, "@gmail.com", sep='')

for i in range (20400,20430):
    print ("s0", i, "@gmail.com", sep='')

for i in range (20500,20530):
    print ("s0", i, "@gmail.com", sep='')

for i in range (20600,20630):
    print ("s0", i, "@gmail.com", sep='')
```

Comment: Using arrays? And looping over them?

Comment: Two loops maybe? One for the starting value i.e. 20100, 20200 etc. and one for 0 - 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the strengths of using Python is that you can nearly always put any loop/structure/if statement in another loop/structure/if statement.

Code:

```
for j in range(20100,20601,100):
    for i in range (j,j+30):
        print ("s0", i, "@gmail.com", sep='')
```

Now, we loop through 2 variables!